# If I come to Canada on a Critical Worker Program, can I move to another province?

Tags: canada, nigerian-citizens

If I have this New Brunswick Critical worker program PNP, if I come into Canada, can I relocate to Ontario / Toronto and leave New Brunswick?

Comment: Will that be as well as setting up a new business in Canada or instead of? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181995/is-meeting-investors-a-valid-reason-for-coming-to-canada

Comment: @Traveller instead of in this case

Answer (score 3):

Once you become a permanent resident of Canada, you have the constitutional right to move across provinces.

However, your PR status can be revoked if you obtain the status by misrepresentation or fraud. For provincial nominee programs, usually the province requires you to have a genuine, good-faith intention to settle in the province that nominated you. You may be denied landing (grant of status) if you do not show your intention to establish yourself in the target province when you first enter Canada. If your actions indicate, on a balance of probabilities, that you *never* had a genuine intention of settling in the nominating province, your status can be revoked and you can be removed and banned from Canada for five years. Intention can be hard to prove, but if you leave the province less than a year after you arrive, it is not that difficult.